# Observable closes, in case of error. How to resolve it?

Tags: angular, observable

Please take a look at this expression:

```
Observable.interval(10000)
.switchMap(() => this.http.get(url))
.catch (err => Observable.empty())
.subscribe(data => render(data))
```

Each 10 seconds we make an http call. If an error happens, observable closes, it doesn't make any calls anymore. How to prevent that?

Comment: Maybe so: `.switchMap(() => this.http.get(url).catch (err => Observable.empty()))` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Observable closed on error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41335813/observable-closed-on-error)

Comment: @Nikolai Your comment is the answer.

Comment: Okay, I believe this will help me to resolve my issues for this assignment. Just want to confirm, Will observable will continue the counting even after getting the error as observable stops the other second it meet an error.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour.  [According to the documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#executing-observables),

> In an Observable Execution, zero to infinite Next notifications may be
>   delivered. If either an Error or Complete notification is delivered,
>   then nothing else can be delivered afterwards.

Comment: Okay, but how about error evaluation? and How to prevent it to stop from causing the error?